# Intellij Grammar Kit - indent based language

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation, grammar-kit

I'm creating a language using the Intellij IDEA Grammar-Kit plugin, and would like the blocks to be indent-based, rather than brace based. The only way I've found to do this so far is to use the `<<indent ...>>` function from https://github.com/kandeshvari/idea-nim/blob/master/src/org/dmitrigb/ideanim/parser/ParserUtil.java.

I have minimized the code from that link to:

```
package org.intellij.sdk.language;

import com.intellij.lang.LighterASTNode;
import com.intellij.lang.PsiBuilder;
import com.intellij.lang.PsiParser;
import com.intellij.lang.impl.PsiBuilderImpl;
import com.intellij.lang.parser.GeneratedParserUtilBase;
import com.intellij.openapi.util.Key;
import com.intellij.psi.TokenType;
import com.intellij.psi.tree.IElementType;
import com.intellij.psi.tree.TokenSet;
import com.intellij.util.containers.IntIntHashMap;


// https://github.com/kandeshvari/idea-nim/blob/master/src/org/dmitrigb/ideanim/parser/ParserUtil.java


public class SPPParserUtil extends GeneratedParserUtilBase {
    private static class ParserState {
        enum PrimaryMode {
            NORMAL, TYPE_DEF, TYPE_DESC
        }

        private PsiBuilder builder;
        private int currentIndent = 0;
        private int pragmaCount = 0;
        private PrimaryMode primaryMode = PrimaryMode.NORMAL;
        private int semiStmtListCount = 0;

        private IntIntHashMap tokIndentCache = new IntIntHashMap();

        ParserState(PsiBuilder builder) {
            this.builder = builder;
        }

        private String getPrecedingWhiteSpace() {
            int wsOffset = 0;
            while (builder.rawLookup(wsOffset - 1) == TokenType.WHITE_SPACE)
                --wsOffset;
            int wsStart = builder.rawTokenTypeStart(wsOffset);
            return builder.getOriginalText().subSequence(wsStart, builder.getCurrentOffset()).toString();
        }

        int getTokenIndent() {
            int tokStart = builder.getCurrentOffset();
            if (tokIndentCache.containsKey(tokStart))
                return tokIndentCache.get(tokStart);

            int indent = -1;
            String ws = getPrecedingWhiteSpace();
            int nlPos = ws.lastIndexOf('\n');
            if (nlPos != -1)
                indent = ws.length() - nlPos - 1;
            tokIndentCache.put(tokStart, indent);
            return indent;
        }
    }

    private static Key<ParserState> parserStateKey = new Key<>("parser-state");

    private static ParserState getParserState(PsiBuilder builder) {
        return builder.getUserData(parserStateKey);
    }

    public static boolean indented(PsiBuilder builder, int level, Parser parser) {
        ParserState state = getParserState(builder);
        int tokIndent = state.getTokenIndent();
        if (tokIndent > state.currentIndent) {
            int prevIndent = state.currentIndent;
            state.currentIndent = tokIndent;
            boolean result = parser.parse(builder, level + 1);
            state.currentIndent = prevIndent;
            return result;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

saved as `SPPParserUtil.java`

---

This is my minimal BNF so far:

```
{
    parserUtilClass='org.intellij.sdk.language.SPPParserUtil'

    tokens=[
        TK_DOT = '.'
        TK_ARROW = '->'
        TK_STAR = '*'
        TK_COLON = ':'

        KW_FILE = 'file'
        KW_IMPORT = 'import'

        TK_EOL = 'regexp:[\n|\r]*'
        TK_IDENTIFIERS = 'regexp:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(,\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*'
        TK_SCOPED_IDENTIFIER = 'regexp:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*'
        TK_SPACE = 'regexp:\s+'
    ]
}



root ::= Program


Program ::=
    ProgramContents <<eof>>
ProgramContents ::=
    FileDefinition ImportBlock? TK_EOL

FileDefinition ::=
    KW_FILE TK_SPACE ScopedIdentifier TK_EOL


ImportLocation ::=
    TK_DOT* ScopedIdentifier
ImportDefinition ::=
    ImportLocation TK_SPACE TK_ARROW TK_SPACE (Identifiers | TK_STAR) TK_EOL
ImportBlock ::=
    KW_IMPORT TK_COLON <<indented ImportDefinition+>>


ScopedIdentifier ::=
    TK_SCOPED_IDENTIFIER
Identifiers ::=
    TK_IDENTIFIERS
```

---

Here is some example code that should pass:

```
file src.classes.class1


import:
    src.classes.class2 -> class2, e2
    src.classes.class3 -> class3, e3
    src.classes.class4 -> *
```

However, whenever I try to use `<<indent ...>>` in my BNF there is always an error: The error described is `':' expected, got ':'`, on the colon following "import". Basically whatever is before the `<<indent ...>>` seems to be consumed by the `<<indent ...>>`. How would I change the BNF / use of the `ParseUtil` to fix this?

---

**EDIT**

I changed the `indented` function to always return true, and not use any of the other Java code and the error persists; this implies that the issue isn't with the Java code but maybe how I'm calling it in the BNF file?

Comment: If you still haven't gotten the answer later, you could also ask here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development .That forum is regularly updated with answers by JetBrains team members.

Comment: Thank you, it's just pending approval at the moment (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10262007575442-Intellij-Grammar-Kit-indent-based-language)